# How do I fix this MySQL trigger statement?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Can't find the issue with it and been trying for a while now

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `checkin_enforcement` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `booking` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF (NEW.checkinDate < NEW.checkoutDate) THEN
            INSERT INTO booking (bookingID, hotelNo, guestNo, checkinDate, checkoutDate, roomNo) VALUES (NEW.bookingID, NEW.hotelNo, NEW.guestNo, NEW.checkinDate, NEW.checkoutDate, NEW.roomNo);

        ELSE
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'The checkin date must be less than the checkout date!';
        END IF;


    END$$
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7**

Comment: Won't this create a loop? before inserting row - trigger called - which insert a row - which again called the trigger - and so on.

Comment: @GurV most likely but I can't get to the stage where I can test it lol

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert the row if condition passes. You only need to throw error when it doesn't.

Also, I changed `on insert` to `on insert or update` because you'll probably want to keep this rule enforced even after the data is inserted in the table. If not, just change it to `on insert`.

Try this:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger checkin_enforcement 
before insert or update on booking
for each row 
begin
    if (new.checkindate >= new.checkoutdate) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'the checkin date must be less than the checkout date!';
    end if;
end$$
```

Comment: Ah okay I see. I'm getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'or update on booking
for each row 
begin
    if (new.checkinDate >= new.check' at line 2 " @GurV

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `checkin_enforcement` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `booking` 
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.checkinDate >= NEW.checkoutDate THEN 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The check-in date must be before the check-out date!'; 
END IF
```

BEGIN is not required after FOR EACH ROW

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.